# Balance of Coulomb and nuclear forces and the rate of spontaneous fission

Tags: nuclear-physics

Consider a heavy isotope that decays by way of spontaneous fission.  In a heavy nucleus, the balance of the Coulomb force and the nuclear force is a delicate one, as seen in the higher probability of emission of alpha particles at the poles of oblong deformed nuclei, where the Coulomb barrier is thinner, than at the waist; and in the spontaneous fission of synthetic elements beyond a certain mass, where the nuclear force is inadequate to compensate for Coulomb repulsion.

Now subject the atoms of the heavy isotope to a magnetic field that is strong enough to create a gradient of electron density at the nucleus as a result of electron orbitals shifting under the influence of the field.  Will there be a tidal force on the nucleus due to a differential balance of the Coulomb and nuclear forces at either end of the gradient?  Is it conceivable that the rate of spontaneous fission could be altered as a result?

Comment: The second paragraph doesn't make much sense. The energy scale of the electrons is wrong for influencing nuclear processes. I don't see any reason why a magnetic field would produce a gradient in electron density.

Comment: @BenCrowell we know that electron orbitals can become deformed under electric potentials, and we know that the Gamow alpha decay calculation is dependent upon minute differences in barrier width.  I think the second paragraph makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Now subject the atoms of the heavy isotope to a magnetic field that is strong >enough to create a gradient of electron density at the nucleus as a result of electron orbitals shifting under the influence of the field. Will there be a tidal force on the nucleus due to a differential balance of the Coulomb and nuclear forces at either end of the gradient? Is it conceivable that the rate of spontaneous fission could be altered as a result?>

I think one is thinking about atomic electrons and

moving the clouds to produce  the gradient of electron density...

just like on earth a tidal force...

but  as i understand..

Fission happens as  the **electrostatic repulsion created**

by the large number of positively **charged protons** contained in a heavy

nucleus  get a pivotal  role .

once the  nucleus can overcome the **strong nuclear force** which holds it together, it can break .

**Fission may  be seen as a "tug-of-war" between the** **strong attractive** nuclear force and the **repulsive** electrostatic force.

In fission reactions, electrostatic repulsion wins.

so i was just thinking that it may not be possible

to bring in the atomic  electron cloud to the scene ...space/region  where nuclear  interactions are taking place.